He enlazado correctamente una imagen con "src" pero al subir con ../ para ingresar a otra carpeta y tomar una imagen, NO lo muestra en el navegador.?
Estoy enlazando correctamente una imagen con "src" en VScode, cúando la imagen está en la raíz del "index.html", no tengo problemas con mostrarla en el navegador, incluso si hay una carpeta adelante, puedo ingresar a la carpeta y buscar la foto sin inconveniente y mostrarla en el navegador. Ademas la extension de VScode me muestra la miniatura de la imagen, indicando que la ruta está enlazada con exito..

El problema llega es cuando intento "regresar" o "subir" una carpeta con "../", si el archivo está sin carpeta, lo puedo enlazar sin problemas, pero si está en otra carpeta, no hay forma de que me muestre en enlace correctamente..
En el primer "src" me carga la imagen, pero si creo una carpeta "img" alli mismo y coloco una imagen dentro de la carpeta "img" e intento llegar a esa imagen, como en el 2do "src" que muestro, esta imagen NO se ve.

No importa como llame a la carpeta, si la borro o la creo 10 veces más, no hay forma de que me muestre la imagen que está bien enlazada como lo muestra en la primera foto.
Pienso que eso deba a alguna restriccion en mi PC pero, no logro dar con la falla, hice las pruebas en otra PC y no tengo problemas con los enlaces.. alguien le ha pasado esto? o alguien tiene una idea que puedo hacer para quitar este gran detalle de mi PC? gracias..

Bueno, despues de muchas pruebas, lo que hice fue cambiar los ficheros a otras carpetas y renombrarlas y ahora si funciona correctamente, quizas se debe a un error de compatibilidad, ya que al crear algunas carpetas uso diferentes formas, desde VScode, desde windows y hasta desde la terminal.. asi que imagino que en alguna de esas creaciones de carpetas, creó alguna que no era compatible o con algún error.. Gracias y espero esto le sirva a alguin al momento de crear carpetas, a veces se pueden llegar a bloquear internamente sin arrojar algún error visible.

Cuando pones ../ lo que ocurre es que se va al directorio padre con respecto al archivo donde se encuentra el script donde pusiste ../. Dependiendo de dónde estén las imágenes, tendrás que poner uno o más ../ e incluir quizá el nombre del directorio donde las imágenes se encuentran. Sea como sea, te aconsejo que evites poner rutas a mano por todo tu proyecto. Es mejor definir constantes con tus rutas, así, si necesitas cambiar alguna ruta, sólo cambias la definición de la constante. Revisa aquí para más detalles.
